# RC-oscillator calibration in real time

Tags: oscillator-clock, temperature, watchdog

This pesky watchdog RC oscillator is at the limit of its 10% tolerance already at room temperature. i was looking to bringing it to more like 5% (it stems from an internak 128 kHz RC oscillator) and the whole -40 ... 125 deg Celsius operating range. Can this reliably be done by reading the temperature of the MCU and applying an algorithm ? Any such working algorithm ?

The *calibration* is actually the adjusting of the number of cycles (of say, 125ms) the watchdog will run for. i.e. for 12.5 seconds I would run the watchdog timer 100 times, nominally. How do I temperature-compensate the 100 figure ?

Comment: You could run a calibration routine whereby you run a timer at the same time as the watchdog timer and then compare the difference between the two... For example run the timer for 1 second and count how many times the watchdog interrupts in that period.

Comment: I think that just measuring the actual frequency at room temperature will be enough to calibrate to a reasonable amount. I don't think you'd get much more precision using temperature dependent calibration. If you want more precision I'd suggest adding an RTC. For example the DS3231.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is pretty detailed but you've missed to tell, which device you are talking about.

I assume you are talking about the ATmega 328P in an Arduino Uno.
AFAIK you can only calibrate the so called `Calibrated internal RC oscillator`, which is used for the main operations.
You cannot calibrate the `Internal 128kHz RC oscillator` from the watchdog.

I think you might have some overhead from your sleep/wake cycles.
Instead of sleeping 100 times to get from 125ms to 12.5s you could sleep for 8s + 4s + 0.5s. Thus sleeping only 3 times. Which might save you some battery life.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using the WDT delta as a temperature sensing method:

https://thecavepearlproject.org/2019/02/25/no-parts-temperature-measurement-with-arduino-pro-mini-to-0-005c-or-better/

Point being that once you have those calibration constants, you could use them use them to correct for WDT variation. OR you might be able to get away with a much shorter  interval than the 1sec we use, with the micros reading as your WDT correction factor more directly.

Comment: "The other big limitation is that you can only do this trick on a voltage regulated system, because RC oscillators are affected by the applied voltage," - this is a nice finding from that article, good thing I have ditched the WDT; otherwise it seems to be concerned with that Silabs temperature sensor.